# Make a method asynchronously inside the class OOP

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

Here's my **Activity** class.

```
export class Activity {
  _name: string
  _goIn: boolean
  
  constructor(name: string) {
    this._name = name;
    this._goIn = false;
  }

  isGoIn() {
    return this._goIn;
  }
  
  setGoIn() {
    // how to set _goIn value to true asynchronously
    this._goIn = true;
  }
  
  setName(name: string) {
    return this._name = name;
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to change the `_goIn` value to true asynchronously.

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is enough to have the code execution deferred until after the call stack has been emptied, then:

```
return Promise.resolve().then(() => this._goIn = true);
```

```js
class Activity {
  _name
  _goIn
  
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name;
    this._goIn = false;
  }

  isGoIn() {
    return this._goIn;
  }
  
  setGoIn() {
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => this._goIn = true);
  }
  
  setName(name) {
    return this._name = name;
  }
}

// demo
let act = new Activity("test");
act.setGoIn().then(() => console.log("2. Asynchronous... now it is", act.isGoIn()));
console.log("1. Synchronous... now it still is", act.isGoIn());
```

Or the same with `async` syntax:

```
async setGoIn() {
    await null;
    this._goIn = true;
}
```

```js
class Activity {
  _name
  _goIn
  
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name;
    this._goIn = false;
  }

  isGoIn() {
    return this._goIn;
  }
  
  async setGoIn() {
    await null;
    this._goIn = true;
  }
  
  setName(name) {
    return this._name = name;
  }
}

// demo
let act = new Activity("test");
(async function() {
    await act.setGoIn();
    console.log("2. Asynchronous... now it is", act.isGoIn());
})(); // execute immediately
console.log("1. Synchronous... now it still is", act.isGoIn());
```

If you have access to [`queueMicroTask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/queueMicrotask) or [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), then those are non-promise solutions:

```
return setTimeout(() => this._goIn = true);
```

`setTimout` returns the id of the timeout, but that gives no clue when the callback gets executed. `queueMicroTask` returns undefined. In that sense a Promise solution is better practice: you can use the returned value in an `await` expression, or else chain a `then` call to it.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I go with the first one.

Comment: Your async function and raw promise examples are not equal. It should be async setGoIn() {
   await Promise.resolve(); this._goIn = true;
}

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, @DmitriyMozgovoy, I inserted an `await`. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 1):

```
async isGoIn() {
    return this._goIn;
 }
```

Remember to use await inside of another async function to be able to get the value. Hopefully this helps. You can also try return a promise instead of the _goIn function